# How to check a TCP port with Cocoa OSX SDK

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I would like to make a cocoa app that will check if some TCP ports are opened on a server.
Return a little red ball if it's closed, or green if it's open...

But I'm little bit confused, what class to use, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

If it is enough just to connect to the the port and close it, the simplest thing is to use the BSD calls:

- create a socket using [socket()](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/socket.2.html)
- connect to the remote port using [connect()](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/connect.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/connect)
- close the socket using [close()](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/close.2.html)

Comment: Ok, but how I can get the information "open" or "closed" ?

Comment: @Miskia: Look at the man page for connect() which I helpfully linked for you.  If it returns 0, the port is open and accepting connections.  If it returns -1, an error occurred, and then you need to check errno to find out why.

Comment: @JeremyP The links which you have provide does not exist any more. Can you please provide the link to do the same, I want to check the status of the port.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP for the update. Is there way to do this in cocoa touch? I want to make an app which can show whether the server port is open or not. Thanks for the help much appreciated.

Comment: @Rajat Have you tried it in Cocoa touch? If it doesn't work (the system calls may be protected by the iOS sandbox) you should probably ask a separate question. There's probably some core foundation functions that let you do the same thing.

Comment: thanks @JeremyP for the details :)