# Is Server online or offline? (Server Status)

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, sockets

I have this really simple PHP Code.

http://pastebin.com/P33nbRTu

And now i want a Objective C Script....

I only know, that i must search after "sockets".
And i found!
[How to check a TCP port with Cocoa OSX SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997126/how-to-check-a-tcp-port-with-cocoa-osx-sdk)
https://discussions.apple.com/message/7815634?messageID=7815634#7815634?messageID=7815634

But the Tutorial is not so 100%-good and because this, I ask here for Code Examples.
I think, someone had this Code on his/hers Hard Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Apple's Readability example application. It includes a way of pinging a server, I believe.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6